# To what extent would the world change if penis sizes of every single male became publicly known to everyone?

Tags: society, sex, social-norms

Extracted from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/5ffyhz/to_what_extent_would_the_world_change_if_penis/)

To what extent would the world change if penis sizes of every single male on earth became publicly known to everyone?

Penis sizes of world leaders, celebrities, sports stars, even Dave from accounting. What impact would it have on our daily life, global politics, interaction with opposite sex, etc?

We assume that it's the erected size and is easily accessible.

Comment: To no extent whatsoever. Contrary to what certain insistent Internet-based advertisers want you to believe, penis size (if not abnormal) has no importance whatsoever.

Comment: There's a saying "it's not the size, but the motion of the ocean" - also keep in mind that *girth* in many instances is more of a factor than *length* in enjoyment...

Comment: Also very few women enjoy a bruised cervix and since internal size of a woman varies just like the external size of a man, it is more a matter of compatibility and technique than anything else.

Comment: I imagine a Wikipedia page, with an infobox like: "Born: yyy.mm.dd, Religion: X, Penis size: 17cm" .... ;-)

Comment: @GraySheep worthless without an image as well. :-D

Comment: Everbody knows the height of the politicians, co-workers and so on. Being below 170cm is clearly a disadvantage for males, that is clearly unjust but so is it. Out of that, practically no one cares. I think, the case would be the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Magic has happened, no-one will care about the numbers

Magic has just taken place. The very first verifiable act of magic in the history of mankind. The question could have been about "breast size", "length of the appendix", "the Na:K ratio as measured at 23:59 UTC on New Years Eve in the year 2010" and the effect would have been the same: people will be much to busy trying to find out "How the hell did **that** happen?!" to be comparing the numbers.

Also size is less important — culturally — than you think, except in niche pornography. If you had asked about **fertility** on the other hand (something you can extend to women as well by the way) then you would have had a case that the numbers would have affected society in some way, once the initial shock subsides. Fertility is a much more significant attribute — culturally speaking — pretty much across the globe.

Comment: @Malkev I know that was meant to be funny. It would be the right tone for Reddit (perhaps). But WB SE? Not so much.

Comment: You'd also have a complete census for every male on the planet. That's gold for various govt agencies. Since it is available for anyone to look up, I assume there's enough identifying info in the database to do accurate count of illegal immigrants, representation allocation, etc.  ... how would this database handle transgender? Maybe Republicans would use the DB to determine who can use which bathroom. "Sorry, 'Joey,' but you're not on The List."

Comment: Great answer! The real magic is in making the data available, not what the data contains. Penis sizes would be pure snigger, for about 24 hours. The real mystery is in how the numbers were found and how they were made available. The rest is fluff. Plus one from me.